# how to include path in string array with the file in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, local-storage

am working with Bitmap.decodeFile(pathname,bOptions), I wanted to include the file detected by the phone in the mean time am using this one

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Pictures/Temp Images";
```

this is only single one of string and I can't include in my array, I want to do is to pass the parameter to my method which is accepting String[] files which includes the pathFile + filename

ex: sd0/pictures/temp file/img1.jpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supossing you  have a variable where the file name is stored:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Pictures/Temp Images" + File.separator + fileName;
```

---

```
public String getPath(String folderName, String fileName){
    return  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + folderName +   File.separator + fileName;
}
```

using the method:

```
String path =  getPath("/Pictures/Temp Images", "img1.jpeg");
```

or

```
 String path =  getPath("/Pictures/Temp Images", fileName);
```

Comment: I just added this path to the loop where I take the filename it working now